# What are the features that Motoblur has that vanilla Android does not have?

Tags: motoblur, vanilla-android

What are the features that [Motoblur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motoblur) has that vanilla Android does not have?

Comment: Did you have a particular version in mind?  Specifically do you mean to include or exclude the current version of Motorola's Android UI, which is no longer called Motoblur?

Comment: I would like to know about the latest released version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Motoblur has a bunch of widget-based applications which bring your social networks and/or emails together for ease of viewing, as well as weather, rss feeds and other simple UI elements/widgets that can come in handy. However, Motoblur keeps a process running in the background for each service (type of widget) and thus many people (myself included) forego it and install a non-Motoblur ROM to conserve RAM, CPU and battery. But if you are an avid user of social networking sites then it is a good choice and worth the battery drain.

Comment: OK, I see that while Motoblur just adds some widgets, Samsung TouchWiz adds real features: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13582/what-are-the-features-that-touchwiz-has-that-stock-android-does-not-have