# What are the features that HTC Sense has that vanilla Android does not have?

Tags: htc-sense, vanilla-android

What are the features that [HTC Sense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTC_Sense) has that vanilla Android does not have?

This question is similar to [What are the features that Motoblur has that vanilla Android does not have?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13579/what-are-the-features-that-motoblur-has-that-stock-android-does-not-have) but for [HTC Sense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTC_Sense).

Answer (score 4):

- integration with social networks (Facebook, Flickr, Twitter), including down to the contacts application, with contact pictures and everything
- free "lost phone" functionality, without the need for a third-party application (eg. Lookout), including remote lock and wipe
- an (arguably) easier to use keyboard, with quick access to numbers and common symbols
- HTC-specific applications (Navigation, Sync, launcher, widgets, etc.)

Keep in mind that all of the eye-candy features offered by Sense do reduce battery life, so it may be desirable to install a third party ROM or remove them from the existing ROM using Titanium Backup.

Comment: I really, REALLY dislike Sense, and completely removed it from my phone, but I've not seen any concrete evidence that the extra processes reduce battery life in an appreciable way. Perhaps you can add a link? I know first-hand that it reduces performance, but also not by a great amount. Oh yeah, for completeness, you might want to add that it changes the look and feel of the UI, and adds some extra features to the notifications pane (on newer models).